# dual boot partitioning

Tags: partitioning

i have a netbook that shipped with a primary partition with windows on it and a hidden partition with operating system restore features. i wish to setup a dual boot windows and ubuntu but im concerned that the repartitioning of the primary hard drive will affect the hidden partition with the windows operating system restore. will the hidden partition be affected when setting up new partitions to allow dual boot.

Comment: you can create a system recovery windows, they contain all the tools most recovery partitions have, on top of that there are some guides on google on how to copy the iso of the recovery disk into the partition, thus making your own recovery partition(bootable)

Answer (score 1):

The hidden partition will not affected if you just shrink other partition (e.g. D:  or E:) to create a partition for Ubuntu it will fine.

Comment: thank you for the prompt answer. i appreciate your input.

Comment: but if you want to shrink your system partition (C:) i suggest you do it from Windows itself